# Laravel relationship to show all posts by authors that they follow

Tags: php, laravel-5

Can normally figure these relationships out but stumped on this one.

I have a basic blog platform that allows user to sign up and post blog posts.

Users can also follow other users.

I am trying to make a view where I can see all of the blog posts by the authors that I follow

I have the normal users table, and then a blog posts table which contains the user_id of the creator.

For followers, I then have a pivot table called followers which has user_id and follower_id.

This is my basic line to get all posts:

```
$posts = Post::orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->get();
```

How can I change that so it only shows the posts where there post user_id is a field that matches in the followers table?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You may try something like this:

### App\User Model:

```
public function favoriteAuthors()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(
        User::class, // as Author
        'followers', // pivot table
        'follower_id', // as follower_id
        'user_id', // as author_id
    );
}

public function posts()
{
    return $this
    ->hasMany(Post::class, 'user_id', 'id')
    ->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC');
}
```

Then load all posts of your favorite authors:

```
$posts = User::with('favoriteAuthors.posts')->find(auth()->user()->id);
```

Also you can use something like this:

```
if($me = auth()->user()) {

    $me->load(['favoriteAuthors.posts']);
}
```

Now the `$me` will contain users that you follw and each users will contain their posts.